# How to Open Texts with Format and Color

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

I am sorry if this Question is not well structured but this is a question that has been puzzling for a while now.

I know how to Read a Text file from the Open file Dialog into a Rich Text box using

```
    DialogResult DR = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (DR == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         string txt = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
         FileStream textFile = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         StreamReader doc = new StreamReader(textFile);
         GetCurrentTextbox().Text = doc.ReadToEnd();
         tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = txt;
     }
```

This works perfectly for Ordinary Text files but the Problem is that if this File was created using Wordpad or MsWord, it shows something like

[image: File]

Pls what can i do????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works perfectly for Ordinary Text files but the Problem is that if this File was created using Wordpad or MsWord, it shows something like

Yes, because those aren't text files - but you're trying to read them as text files.

If you need to read a Word/Wordpad document, you'll either need to use Office Interop, or possibly a third party library which understands the file format. Either way, you won't be able to just set the `Text` property of a control to anything to get formatted text. You might be able to convert it to RTF and then use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).